# Golang dynamic access to a struct property

Tags: go, struct

I am writing a quick ssh config to json processor in golang. I have the following stuct:

```
type SshConfig struct {
    Host string
    Port string
    User string
    LocalForward string
    ...
}
```

I am currently looping over every line of my ssh config file and splitting the line on spaces and checking which property to update.

```
if split[0] == "Port" {
    sshConfig.Port = strings.Join(split[1:], " ")
}
```

Is there a way to check a property exists and then set it dynamically?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking, but why are you not serializing your configuration to something like YAML or JSON?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [reflect](http://godoc.org/reflect) package to set a field by name:

```
// setField sets field of v with given name to given value.
func setField(v interface{}, name string, value string) error {
    // v must be a pointer to a struct
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || rv.Elem().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return errors.New("v must be pointer to struct")
    }

    // Dereference pointer
    rv = rv.Elem()

    // Lookup field by name
    fv := rv.FieldByName(name)
    if !fv.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("not a field name: %s", name)
    }

    // Field must be exported
    if !fv.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot set field %s", name)
    }

    // We expect a string field
    if fv.Kind() != reflect.String {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s is not a string field", name)
    }

    // Set the value
    fv.SetString(value)
    return nil
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var config SshConfig

...

err := setField(&config, split[0], strings.Join(split[1:], " "))
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/16vqu2yhw6d)

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflect package to dynamically inspect structs at runtime. See [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) and [blog](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).

But if all you want to do is read the file into a structure its better to use something like `map[string]string`. Inspecting maps at runtime is much cleaner (e.g. you could `range` over it, check membership and ... in one line).

```
m := make(map[string]string)
...
m[split[0]] = strings.Join(split[1:], " ")
```