# How can I choose which struct member to update at runtime?

Tags: go, data-structures, struct, updates

Say I have a struct in Go that looks like this:

```
LastUpdate struct {
     Name string `yaml:"name"`
     Address string `yaml:"address"`
     Phone string `yaml:"phone"`
}
```

Now say I want to create a function that accepts the name of the field (eg. "Phone") and then updates that field to a value, like today's date.

How can I build the function in a way that it will accept the name of the field and update that field in the struct?

I know that I could do an IF clause for each scenario (if field == "Phone") {var.LastUpdate.Phone = time.Now().Date()}, but I'd like to build this function so that I don't have to go add an IF clause every time I add a new member to this struct in the future. Thoughts?

Comment: The `reflect` package in the standard library can do introspection on types like structs. One would need to iterate through the fields sequentially to look it up by name. Setting field values is possible, but gets very tricky when passing in potentially incompatible values (or types). It's a slippery slope and not for the faint of heart. If you are new to `go` I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang dynamic access to a struct property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961245/golang-dynamic-access-to-a-struct-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to set a field by name.

```
// setFieldByName sets field with given name to specified value.
// The structPtr argument must be a pointer to a struct. The
// value argument must be assignable to the field.
func setFieldByName(structPtr interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {

    v := reflect.ValueOf(structPtr)
    v = v.Elem()            // deference pointer
    v = v.FieldByName(name) // get field with specified name

    if !v.IsValid() {
        return errors.New("field not found")
    }

    v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))

    return nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var lu LastUpdate
setFieldByName(&lu, "Name", "Russ Cox")
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OPwZ2spMJl-)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you