# Calling valiable name from another variable

Tags: arrays, go, aws-sdk-go

Please help to call the variable from another variable.

I have the script which is taking EC2 instances and return in "*ec2.Instance" variable.

I can print information from static text, for example :

```
fmt.Println(instance.InstanceType) // t3.small
```

But I have the list of reqired fields like and don't know how dynamic use name from this list :

```
fields := []string{"InstanceId", "InstanceType", "PrivateIpAddress"}
for i := range fields {
    fmt.Println(fields[i])
    fmt.Println(instance.fields[i]) // Not correct ... :(
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're asking You cannot "call variables". You call functions.  And what is "not correct" (other than the fact that you're trying to access an unexported field)?  What error do you see?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. The person is trying to access a set of properties in a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection to do this in go.

The key takeaway is you need to "analyze" the returned value at runtime and access properties by name from the "reflected" structure. Reflection basically means analyzing objects at runtime.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type whatever struct {
    cat string
    dog string
    animals int
    something string

}

func main() {

    wantProps := []string{ "cat", "animals"}
    we := whatever{cat: "meow", animals: 22}
    r := reflect.ValueOf(we)
    for _, propName := range wantProps {
        prop := r.FieldByName(propName)
        fmt.Println(propName, prop)
    }
}
```

More details:

[Golang dynamic access to a struct property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961245/golang-dynamic-access-to-a-struct-property)